# "response data" or "responses data"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

I am not sure if I should use plural or singular. I have many responses. I have a sentence like:

> We summarise the responses data

vs.

> We summarise the response data

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the term is **response data**. The data received as responses to a survey, for example.

The data from the response is written as: response data. This is a common phenomenon in English. **Results of the tests** becomes: **test results**. These are not formal compound nouns. They are noun phrases using two nouns in order to shorten text.

1) 
View Survey Data
When participants complete a survey, **you can view the response data** [bolding mine] on the Analyze tab of the Survey Builder. If you don’t see the information that you need on the Analyze tab, you can create a custom report type for survey responses.

REQUIRED EDITIONS AND USER PERMISSIONS

[Trailblazer community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_view_survey_data.htm&type=5)

2) Exporting **Response Data** [bolding mine]

[Qualtrics](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/employee-experience/creating-360-project/data-tab-360/exporting-response-data-360/)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether we think of ***data*** as singular or plural, the word ***response*** in OP's example is an (adjectival) ***noun adjunct / attributive noun*** usage.

Attributive nouns are usually ***singular***, as in *He bought a **car** radio*, but in certain contexts, such as *They met in a **singles** bar*, the plural form has become idiomatically established.

Things get more complicated because ***possessive*** forms can also be used instead of "unvarnished" (singular ***or*** plural) attributive nouns, such as *New students must enroll on a **beginner's** course*. Where in *speech*, no-one really knows whether that ***s*** represents a possessive apostrophe attached to singular ***beginner*** (the "Saxon genitive" form), or a morphological inflection creating the plural noun ***beginners***. So there's often confusion about whether to ***write*** that apostrophe.

Not all permutations of singular / plural / possessive work in all contexts though - "acceptable" usages include, for example,...

> 1: *a student workbook*  ("student" = ***attributive*** noun, "workbook" = ***head*** noun)
>    2: *a students workbook*
>    3: *a student's workbook*
>    4: *a students' workbook*  (we don't write/say the implied possessive ***s*** after the apostrophe here)
>    5: *a children's book* (but *this* example shows that we do if the plural doesn't already end in ***s***)

Doubtless *some* prescriptive grammarians would argue about the "correctness" of some of the above examples, but they certainly all occur. If this seems a bit daunting, you might find it comforting to know that [*Linguists have been trying to figure out what’s going on with singulars and plurals inside English compound nouns for at least 30 years*](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-nouns) ("Quick & Dirty Tips" from *Grammar Girl*).

---

Returning to OP's specific example, all the following are syntactically valid...

> 6: *We summarise the response data*
>    7: *We summarise the data*
>    8: *We summarise the responses*
>    9: *We summarise the response*

Strictly speaking, I think I could argue for "possessive" forms of the above *(We summarise the **response's** data, We summarise the **responses'** data)* being at least "syntactically valid". They might even be "idiomatically acceptable" in a contrived context where the ***response / responses*** have some other relevant "attribute" besides "data" - in which case the word ***data*** would likely be heavily stressed to accentuate the contrast with other attributes (*such as **fonts***)...

> 10: *We record the response **data** [content], but we don't record things like the font it was written in*

---

I realise this isn't what most learners want to hear, but the awkward truth of the matter is that (style guides and opinionated grammarians excepted) there isn't really a consensus on which permutations of the above (singular or plural, possessive or not) are "syntactically valid" and/or "idiomatically established / acceptable". I think all you can really hope to do is learn which combinations are specifically ***not*** idiomatically acceptable *for specific pairs of "attributive" and "head" nouns*.

To pour a bit more "petrol on the flames", I'll just present this final example which I personally would consider "more or less" acceptable with the first instance of ***response*** replaced by plural ***responses*** OR by the singular / plural possessive forms ***response's***, **responses'**...

> *We analyse the response **method of collection**, not the response data [content] itself*

(Where the highlighting in that example indicated heavy spoken stress *in the actual utterance* - it's not me calling attention to those specific words because they're particularly relevant to my analysis.)

---

TL;DR: In OP's *specific* context, his first version is idiomatically unacceptable. Several other versions besides his second suggestion *are* acceptable, but this doesn't mean the same combinations of singular / plural, with / without a Saxon genitive will necessarily be seen as "okay" or not with different pairs of attributive + head nouns used in this way.