# How properly to write "account ids" or "accounts ids"?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I have multiple lists. Every list include numbers - identificators of accounts. How properly shortly to write "accoun**t** ids" or "accoun**ts** ids"?(Context -  some data in list. Every account has one unique identificator). How properly shortly to write "accoun**ts** lists" or "accoun**t** lists".

**P.S.** This question need to explain how to make short naming of entity for programming code.

Comment: Take a look at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222064/response-data-or-responses-data/222076#222076  Does it answer your question?  (attributive nouns are singular and lack determiners by default)

Comment: I don't understand what does it mean for this example. Can you get me explain for this question, need to use account or accounts?

Comment: 'Attributive nouns are singular' - so _account IDs_ (note capitalisation).

Comment: Nouns used as adjective do not take an s: Account IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, think of the label (such as "account" or "user") as an adjective, not a noun that is plural because there is more than one "thing".

As adjectives, the standard form is "account IDs" and "User IDs" rather than plural ("accounts IDs").

Also, the standard abbreviation for "Identification" is "ID", two capital letters, not "Id" or "id", which look too much like words that should be pronounced.