# Should attributive nouns be always Singular?

Tags: attributive-nouns

> 1. We saw rows of **soldiers tents.**
> 2. We saw rows of **soldier tents.**
> 3. We saw rows of **soldiers' tents.**

Which of the above is the most accurate sentence?

Comment: They're all "valid" - as is singular possessive ***soldier's tents***, which you left out. But ***plural*** possessive (your last version) is by far the most common form for the exact pair you're asking about.

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soldier+tents%2Csoldiers+tents%2Csoldier%27s+tents%2Csoldiers%27+tents&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoldier%20tents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoldiers%20tents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoldier%20%27s%20tents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoldiers%20%27%20tents%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csoldier%20tents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoldiers%20tents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoldier%20's%20tents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoldiers%20'%20tents%3B%2Cc0) the evidence from Google NGrams.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, I deliberately left out the singular possessive as I had the notion of a single soldier owning a single tent. Btw, is 3 equally valid? Is the possessive form an attributive noun? *A students centre* or *a students' centre*, which one is correct when the students do not own it, but when it means *a centre for them*?

Comment: I saw him at the student center. But soldiers' tents.

Comment: @Lambie you mean the attributive noun *student* should be in singular, right? Also, *soldiers'* in the possessive form because the tents they own? Why not *soldiers tents* if they are *meant for the soldiers*?

Comment: Yes, student center. Some nouns have not reached a point where they can be adjectivized. Here, you really have a possessive: The soldiers' tents were huge but the campers' tents were quite small. And when a noun does become an adjective, it is never plural.

Comment: @Lambie Regarding the singularity of the attributive noun, pls see what "ThoghtCo" says, ""It is normal that the first or attributive noun of a sequence will be singular," says Geoffrey Leech. "Yet studies of recent English . . . have noted the apparently increasing variety of formations with a plural attributive noun". (https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012) So, can't we use *students centre* in plural?

Comment: Only in **well-recognized phrases like given in those examples**. Not here for soldiers or campers.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you.

Comment: @mahmudkoya: As you can see from the NGram I linked to above, your version 3 (plural possessive **soldiers' tents**) is at least 10 times more common than any of the other three versions. Is that sufficient evidence of "validity" to you?