# Electoral system or Electoral systems?

Tags: grammatical-number

What are the difference and meanings of

Example 1:

- Electoral system (singular)
- Electoral systems (plural)

Note the page title below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_system

https://consoc.org.uk/the-constitution-explained/electoral-systems/

Example 2:

- Engineering system design (singular)
- Engineering systems design  (plural)

This post is slightly different from the questions below:

Refs:

[System(s) Analyst - Should System be Plural or Singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533323/systems-analyst-should-system-be-plural-or-singular) This doesn't explain the rule

[When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) I don't understand from this link.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229234/image-directory-or-images-directory-pluralizing-of-attributive-nouns/229726#229726

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the US we would tend to say "Department of Engineering System Design", even if that department may design two or more different systems.  Similarly, in the US we have "shoe stores" and not "shoes stores", even if that store stocks more than one shoe.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing special here: "One system" - "Many systems".

There is sometimes a bit of nuance when there are several systems that work together, and so could be thought of as one large system.  For example in the USA, there are many systems for electing people: the system for President, the system for Congresspeople, the systems in each state, and in each city.  You might think of these as multiple electoral systems, or as one big complex electoral system.

Generally, attributive nouns are singular. "Systems design" is sometimes used, to mean "design of multiple systems", consulting ngrams suggests that it is almost interchangeable with "system design".

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!